# Делаю поиск на сайте но выводится ошибка

Tags: python, django

Сделал поиски на сайте поиск производиться по названию . Но при вводе текста в строку поиска выводиться ошибка . Или какой нибудь другой вариант создания поиска на сайте
данные со Traceback Switch back to interactive view

```
File "D:\Users\MAestro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "D:\Users\MAestro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  115.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "D:\Users\MAestro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  113.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

Exception Type: TypeError at /news/search/
Exception Value: post_search() missing 1 required positional argument: 'request'
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

views.py

```
def post_search(request):
    form = SearchForm()
    if 'query' in request.GET:
        form = SearchForm(request.GET)
        search = request.GET['username']


        if form.is_valid():
            cd = form.cleaned_data
            results = SearchQuerySet().models(Articles).filter(content=cd['query']).load_all()

            total_results = results.count()
    return render(request,
                  'news/posts.html',
                  {'form': form,
                   'search': search,
                   'cd': cd,
                   'results': results,
                   'total_results': total_results})
```

urls.py

```
path('search/', views.post_search, name='post_search'),
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms


class SearchForm(forms.Form):
    query = forms.CharField()
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from taggit.managers import TaggableManager

class Articles(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length= 200)
    post = models.TextField()
    date = models.DateTimeField()
    img = models.ImageField(upload_to='', default="default_value")
    tags = TaggableManager()
    article_like = models.IntegerField(default='0')
    article_dislike = models.IntegerField(default='0')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

posts.html

```
<div class="row">
    <div  class="col-lg-1 col-md-1"></div>
    <div style="background-color:white; height: 500px ; widht: 100% ;" class="col-lg-3 col-md-3">


   {% if "query" in request.GET %}
        <h1>Posts containing "{{ cd.query }}"</h1>
        <h3>Found {{ total_results }} result{{ total_results|pluralize }}</h3>
        {% for result in results %}
            {% with post=result.object %}
                <h4><a href="{{ post.get_absolute_url }}">{{ post.title }}</a></h4>
                {{ post.body|truncatewords:5 }}
            {% endwith %}
            {% empty %}
            <p>There are no results for your query.</p>
        {% endfor %}
        <p><a href="{% url 'post_search' %}">Search again</a></p>
    {% else %}
        <h1>Search for posts</h1>
        <form action="{% url 'post_search' %}" method="get">
            <h3>Поиск</h3><input  style=" border: 3px solid #4242A3; border-radius: 15px ; " type="text" name="search" value=" Поиск "> <br>
            <input type="submit" value="Search">
        </form>
    {% endif %}
    </div>
```

Comment: Что непонятно в тексте ошибки?

Comment: Все или как ее решить?